# Child divs inside a flexbox with fixed height and overflow auto does not set dynamically its height

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-grid

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000
}

.child {
  padding: 10px;
}

.child:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #c1c1c1
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="box">
      Boxes
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Boxes
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Boxes
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Boxes
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Boxes
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="box">
      Boxes
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="box">
      Boxes
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Boxes
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The child divs inside a flexbox does not change dynamically when the content increases.
P.S. the parent div has a fixed hright with overflow auto.

I want the height to be same across all child if the height of any child increases.
Please find the code here : 
https://jsfiddle.net/v7tcar5n/3/

Comment: You're asking how to have a dynamic height with a fixed height. You can't have both, you need to choose one or the other.

Comment: consider a nested container where you apply flexbox

Comment: Adding a nested container worked for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the height of the container, then you will get the desired result because the `align-items: stretch` flex default.

```
.container{
display:flex;
overflow:auto;
border:1px solid #000;
}
```

With 'stretch' items are stretched to fit the container.

Comment: but that's the requirement, i need the height and scrollbar on the container.

Comment: It's the correct answer.... if you have a fixed height you can have dynamic height.....